# how to send value from android app to field in thingspeak

Tags: android, arduino, project, iot

I am trying to send value of text field to thingspeak channel.

```
   OFF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run()  {
                    try
                    {


                       String myUrl="https://thingspeak.com/update?api_key=MY_Write_KEY"+myField.getText().toString();

                        URL thingWrite=new URL(myUrl);
                        HttpURLConnection myServer=(HttpURLConnection)thingWrite.openConnection();
                        myServer.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        myServer.setDoOutput(true);
                        int respCode=myServer.getResponseCode();



                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {}
                }
            }).start();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Its"+myField.getText().toString()+"Now",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
        }
    });
```

But when I do not enter any value in the text field "myField" only then the channel gets updated with null in the field. when ever I enter a string in the myField it does not update the channel.